# pkg_config_path error on building with docker

Tags: oracle, docker, go, build, pkg-config

**When I am building an image for my Go application through docker, I am getting the following error:**

**# pkg-config --cflags oci8**

Package oci8 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `oci8.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'oci8' found
pkg-config: exit status 1

I have set the environment variable in my Dockerfile also. But still the issue persists.
My Dockerfile is:

```
*FROM golang:1.9
ARG app_env
ENV APP_ENV $app_env
ENV GOPATH /home/nupur/mapi-go
ENV PKG_CONFIG_PATH /home/nupur/mapi-go
ENV ORACLE_HOME /usr/include/oracle/11.2/client64
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib
WORKDIR /home/nupur/mapi-go/src/DockerApp/blDocker
ADD . .
RUN go build /home/nupur/mapi-go/src/DockerApp/blDocker/launch.go
ENTRYPOINT ["./launch"]
EXPOSE 8093*
```

Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure had you solved this problem cause this problem has been asked two years ago ...
From your Dockerfile, you already set the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`, but after setting WORKDIR you used `ADD` command, so you add files to your WORKDIR that does not include your `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`. I think you should use `ls` for your `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to see if any file called oci8.pc exited. In this case I suggest to use `COPY` command to move oci.pc to `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` specially.

Answer (score 0):

> Package oci8 was not found in the pkg-config search path.

Since a Go Lang image is being used, the unix package `pkg-config` cannot be  accessed here. You could instead use an Ubuntu image and install the relevant package via the `apt` package manager.

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y pkg-config
RUN apt install -y golang
```

Comment: I've only come across this when trying to build a GTK4 application with Rust bindings in a Docker container.