# Error building Go + go-oci8 with docker in WSL2

Tags: oracle, go, pkg-config, oci8, wsl-2

I build a Go project and try to connect exist remote Oracle Database using go-oci8.
The environment is wsl2 on window 10. I'm using Oracle Instant Client 21.1.
My oci8.pc location:

```
/usr/lib/pkgconfig
```

My oci8.pc file:

```
prefix=/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_1
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${prefix}
includedir=${prefix}/sdk/include

glib_genmarshal=glib-genmarshal
gobject_query=gobject-query
glib_mkenums=glib-mkenums

Name: oci8
Description: oci8 library
Libs: -L${libdir} -lclntsh
Cflags: -I${includedir}
Version: 21.1
```

My Dockerfile:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM golang:latest AS builder
ENV GO111MODULE=on

# Download modules
WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/github.com/hadeshunter/todo
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

# Build
COPY . ./
RUN CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix nocgo -o /todo .

# Run
FROM scratch
COPY --from=builder /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/
COPY --from=builder /todo ./
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["./todo"]
```

My ~/.zshrc, I add

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_1:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I using command run

> go run main.go

Everything is success. But when run build with docker

> docker-compose build && docker-compose run --rm --service-ports todo

I get error:

```
# pkg-config --cflags  -- oci8
Package oci8 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `oci8.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'oci8' found
pkg-config: exit status 1
ERROR: Service 'todo' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix nocgo -o /todo .' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Does anyone give me suggestion, pls?

Comment: you need to set this up within the docker container. You can run `pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config` to get the locations. You can use this instruction into your docker file to set up the environnement variable `ENV PKG_CONFIG_PATH [path]` this question is closely related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47407093/pkg-config-path-error-on-building-with-docker

Comment: it is unclear when you say `my zhrc` or `my system` if you talk abou the host machine or the containerized machine.

Comment: If you want to make things a lot easier on yourself, check if there is a pure Go driver for oracle that meets your requirements. If you use a pure Go driver, CGO is not required and probably neither are any other installations and setup steps. Here is one I know of: https://github.com/sijms/go-ora

Comment: @mh-cbon Thank you I will try. As you can see, that related question has been around for a long time and it has not been clearly answered.

Comment: @TehSphinX Thank you, I searched for quite a few articles and barely found a clear Pure Go Oracle Driver. Hope this package will be fine.

Comment: @TríHuỳnh, yes I think it is pretty new. I saw an article about it in `Golang Weekly` recently and it caught my eye. I helped set up a connection to oracle a few years back using `github.com/mattn/go-oci8` and it was "difficult". Not blaming mattn's repo, just the additional GCO hurdle makes it a lot harder. Here the Golang Weekly issue: https://golangweekly.com/issues/336

Comment: @TehSphinX I'm connecting success to Oracle DB with go-ora https://github.com/sijms/go-ora now. Thank you very much. This pure Go driver work well without config Oracle Instant Client.

Comment: @TríHuỳnh Thanks for letting me know, as I haven't had the change to play with it myself yet.